# IndexError: string index out of range: One more time

Tags: python

I have the next problem. The code is perfect to catch the hashtag but... how can I put in the second "while" that the lane is finished?

If I put this lane:

```
hash = '#hhhh #asdasd'
```

The code won´t compile. How can I change the while? Thank in advance.
Exception:

```
while hash[indexA + 1] not in {' ', '#'}:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Here is the code:

```
hash = '#hhhh #asdasd '
indexA = 0
copy = ''
indexB = indexA

while indexA < len(hash):
    indexB = indexA
    copy = ''

    if hash[indexA] == '#' and indexA + 1 < len(hash):
        while hash[indexA + 1] not in {' ', '#'}:
            indexA += 1
            copy = hash[indexB:indexA + 1]

        if len(copy) > 1:
            print('newHashtag: ' + copy)

        if hash[indexA + 1] == ' ':
            indexA += 1

    else:
        indexA += 1
```

Comment: `while indexA < len(hash) - 1`

Comment: This code works in my Python interpreter. Btw, `hash` is a built-in function in Python, it's not a good idea to overwrite it.

Comment: you should really use regex for this, if I understand what you are doing. You could even just use `split` if your strings will always be regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with index because You don't have check for length of hash. This should work:

```
hash = '#hhhh #asdasd'
indexA = 0
copy = ''
indexB = indexA

while indexA < len(hash):
    indexB = indexA
    copy = ''

    if hash[indexA] == '#' and indexA + 1 < len(hash):
        while indexA + 1 < len(hash) and hash[indexA + 1] not in {' ', '#'}:
            indexA += 1
            copy = hash[indexB:indexA + 1]

        if len(copy) > 1:
            print('newHashtag: ' + copy)

        if indexA + 1 < len(hash) and hash[indexA + 1] == ' ':
            indexA += 1

    else:
        indexA += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find tags in string, you can do it much easier and using much pythonic way:

```
some_string = "#tag1 #tag2 something else #tag3"
tags = [tag.strip("#") for tag in some_string.split() if tag.startswith("#")]

>>> print tags
['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
```

In case of tags without spaces, you may write something like this:

```
some_string = "#tag1 #tag2 something else #tag3 #moretags#andmore"
tags = []
for tag in some_string.split():
    if '#' in tag:
        multi_tags = tag.split('#')
        tags.extend([t for t in multi_tags if t])

>>> tags
['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'moretags', 'andmore']
```

Comment: According to OP code, there may not be spaces between tags, so your solution may not work.

Comment: @Danicroquebelmar, after a years of experience of using Python you'll program like me :)But try to solve your task using Python features, but not write Basic-like code using Python :)